# Как избавиться от переходных полос после применения transform skew CSS3?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css3, адаптивная-верстка, transform

Сверстал блок, применив transform, так-как искажается весь блок, слева использовал before, но теперь, между блоком и before идет белая полоса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[Сайт, где наблюдается это](http://gazenergostroy.webflow.io/#guarantees)

Comment: например `.garant-left-block::before {     width: 101vw; } `

Comment: @Elena Там тогда идет наслоение, и полоса становится синей